# Calling ancestor function

Tags: python

I call ancestor **init** function but this doesn't call ancestor function *set_param()*, it calls descadent function.It means in my script, that *fathers* variable *self.a* isn't initialized. Can you explain it to me? Thank You.

```
 class father (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.set_param()

    def set_param(self):
        self.a = 'father' # isn't initialized

class son (father):
    def __init__(self):
        father.__init__(self)
        self.set_param()

    def set_param(self):
        self.b = 'son'

person = son()
```

Comment: The names alone suggest that you are misusing inheritance. A son is not a kind of father.

Comment: I *hope* the OP uses those words in the sense of "parent class" and "child class", which are fairly common terminology.

Comment: Class names should follow the `CamelCase` style. Python isn't java, by the way, you don't need all those getter and setter functions.

Answer (score 1):

`self.set_param()` gets called twice, from `son.__init__` and from `father.__init__`, but both times it calls `son.set_param` because `type(self)` is `son` in both cases. `father.set_param` is never called.

Comment: From your answer result two questions: a) Why son isn' t father child? b) Why can parent call child function? It means: Why does father.__init__() cal son.set_param()?